Bulk upload of email templates
How to upload 100+ email templates doc file to sandbox classic email template folder?

You can't mass upload Word Documents as email templates. You have several options available, such as using the Metadata API, the SOAP API, the REST API, the Tooling API, the Bulk API, and probably a few others that escape my memory at the moment. However, in every single case, the payloads must be formatted in a particular style depending on if you're uploading HTML or plain text, as well as any attachments and the type of email template.
